# Is there a way to make SignalR core work with internet explorer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, signalr

I am using the alpha release currently , it works with Edge, FireFox , Chrome but does not work with IE .

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the ES5 javascript client for it to work with IE. For example:

```
import { HubConnection } from '@aspnet/signalr-client/dist/browser/signalr-clientES5-1.0.0-alpha2-final.js';
```

Comment: your answer helped , have to add we must also add those 
lines
var transportType = signalR.TransportType.LongPolling;
chatHub = new signalR.HttpConnection('/markethub', { transport: transportType, logger: logger });
other wise it wont work . Not sure why isn't auto detection working too .

Comment: I can connect with websockets in IE without issue.